# CodeIgniter [Image Manipulation Library] will not let me resize image first, and THEN watermark it

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-processing

The process only works in reverse, watermarking it, and then resizing. That can lead to problems if the images were of different resolutions.

I try to do resize first, then watermark, but there isn't any watermarking in the image.

my controller:

```
$this->load->library('manipulate_img');
$this->manipulate_img->watermark($image_data);
$this->manipulate_img->resize($image_data);
```

my library:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Manipulate_img
{

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->library('image_lib');
    }

    public function resize($pic_path) 
    {
        /*
         * Start resizing to 640px x 480px
         */
        $config['source_image'] = $pic_path;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width'] = 640;
        $config['height'] = 480;
        $this->CI->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->CI->image_lib->resize();
        $this->CI->image_lib->clear();

        return true;
    }

    public function watermark($pic_path)
    {
        $config['source_image'] = $pic_path;
        $config['wm_font_size'] = 11;
        $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
        $config['wm_font_path'] = 'fonts/secretcode/SECRCODE.TTF';
        $config['wm_shadow_color'] = '000000';
        $config['wm_text'] = 'www.example.com // ' . $this->CI->session->userdata('username') . date(" // F d, Y // h:iA s ") . 'seconds';
        $this->CI->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->CI->image_lib->watermark();
        $this->CI->image_lib->clear();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think, You need to callback the watermark function

Comment: What do you mean callback the function? I called it (`$this->CI->image_lib->watermark();`) in the `watermark` method in the library

Comment: see this http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php . You need to call the watermark function after the resize.

Comment: Call me dumb, but maybe I'm just misunderstanding. But when I do this `$this->load->library('manipulate_img');
$this->manipulate_img->resize($image_data);
$this->manipulate_img->watermark($image_data);` in my controller, wouldn't the output be the same for if i were to call the watermark function from within the separate library/class?

Comment: Check the pic path and the image path. Make sure the files exist. Otherwise, it will not work

Comment: Hello. I'm having same problem. I can't watermark and resize same image. I can either resize or watermark.
                $this->image_lib->initialize($options);
                $this->image_lib->watermark();
                $this->image_lib->resize();
                $this->image_lib->clear();